# What part of the website is the link thumbnail?

Tags: html, icons, thumbnails

This question is kind of different but for example, if I were to send the link of my website through Instagram Direct Messages, the link shows up with a thumbnail of the logo and then my description. I am trying to understand where that thumbnail is coming from because it is not the icon of the tab. My client wants me to change the thumbnail image, but I am trying to figure out where it is reading it from so that I can change it in my custom HTML.

Comment: I have searched for this everywhere but can't find anything on google or stack overflow, any help would be great!

Comment: Most social networks parse and understand Open Graph tags: http://ogp.me/ - you want `og:image`, most likely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That image is generally served as `og:image` metadata from the [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/).

If you wanted to control the image that is displayed then you would want to place following `<meta>` element within your `<head>` element:

`<meta property="og:image" content="mycustomimage.png">`

The exact image dimensions are harder to pin down. Facebook (who authored the Open Graph protocol) [recommends images that are at least 1080px wide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices/#images).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried this and it worked when I am emailing the link. Through email, it does show the image I want it to show, however, when it done through Instagram it still shows the original pixelated logo I'm assuming possibly found on the site itself. The reason it is important for it to be good on Instagram is because the link is sent to many different clients on that platform. Is there a reason it is not using the image I am setting with the og:image property on instagram, but it is through email?

Comment: @josephT Instagram caches the results for a while. You may be able to clear that cache at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ - it works for Facebook/Messenger, and Instagram's owned by them. I can't guarantee it works for Instagram, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz that did it! Thanks!